# Global variable x is not defined

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guy !
I am getting a following error
Global variable x is not defined.

```
def where1(msg):
    global x1
    x1 = msg.data
def where2(msg):
    global y1
    y1 = msg.data

def ground():
    global cmd
    cmd = rospy.Publisher("/atrv/motion", Twist)
    rospy.init_node("ground")   
    rospy.Subscriber("/box_positiona", Float64, where1)
    rospy.Subscriber("/box_positionb", Float64, where2)
    print x1
    print y1
    rospy.spin() # this will block untill you hit Ctrl+C
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ground()
```

Thanks, looking forward for answers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174743/global-variable-x-is-not-defined/) by [jashanvir](https://answers.ros.org/users/14866/jashanvir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2014-06-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-06-24**:
Please copy and paste error message directly.

**Comment by [jashanvir](https://answers.ros.org/users/14866/jashanvir/) on 2014-06-24**:
NameError: global name 'x1' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any code that sets this variable globally?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0